# Primefaces fileupload big file(400M) in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, primefaces

all!
I am using the jsf 2.0 and primefaces 4.0.
When the file was stored in the harddisk， and the handleFileUpload function was execute to the end, but the IE keeps the uploading status.I hava tryed many times about the web.xml config and the upload code, I think it`s not about them because when upload small file(less than 400M) the code execute perfect.So I think it`s something wrong with IE browser, anyone meet the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

With Primefaces 4.0 and JSF2 I think you must be using IE11. Even i got an issue with IE 11 but for IE10 its working.

With 3.5 it was reverse that IE10 was blocked and IE 11 was working. Its really difficult to support IE browsers.